# How to move substrings to new columns?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

So, I've got an MYSQL Database with just one table called `log`. In that table there's a column called `Date_Time` in which all data looks like this: `2019-04-01-02.24.34.657661`. I want to make two seperate columns called `Time` and `Date` in which I want to put the date and time from the `Date_Time` column, obviously.

The code, which you can see below is what I've already tried. As you can see, I know how to select a substring, but I don't know how to put it in new, seperate columns. I hope you can help me.

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(Date_Time, 1, 10) AS Date
from log;
```

By the way, the database has 8.000.000 lines, just so you know :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an `UPDATE` statement :

```
update log
   set Date = SUBSTRING(Date_Time, 1, 10), 
       Time = SUBSTRING(Date_Time, 11)
```

Seems that `Date_Time` is a string type column. Since you are directly using `SUBSTRING()` function without type conversion.

Comment: Thank you very much! That worked perfectly fine! :)

Comment: Well, it worked with "Date" but when I enter the following code:

"update log set Time = SUBSTRING(Date_Time, 12, 19);"

It says: "ERROR 1206 (HY000): The total number of locks exceeds the lock table size"

Comment: @user11743296 this error is related to your DB. Consult him/her.

Answer (score 0):

Try using cast:

```
Select cast(Date_Time as date) as Date, cast(Date_Time as time) as Time
from log;
```